# Extracting date and time from a binary data string using

Tags: python, datetime, struct, reverse-engineering

I have a third party application that stores time series data as a packed binary file. I am trying to create a tool to convert the data stored in this file.

Shown below is a snapshot of this data.

```
41 16 00 00 01 00 D7 11 00 00 01 00 E8 55 A6 20 08 1E D0 08 00 00 00 60 59 D5 
86 40 03 E8 F5 2C 22 08 1E D0 08 00 00 00 00 C0 0B 87 40 01 E8 95 B3 23 08 1E 
D0 08 00 00 00 40 1E 00 87 40 01 E8 35 3A 25 08 1E D0 08 00 00 00 60 13 F8 86
40 01 E8 D5 C0 26 08 1E D0 08 00 00 00 40 65 09 87 40 01 E8 75 47 28 08 1E D0 
08 00 00 00 20 8A F6 86 40 01 E8 15 CE 29 08
```

I know that this block of data corresponds to the following values.

```
5/13/2013 17:46:11.558  730.6686401
5/13/2013 17:46:14.118  737.46875
5/13/2013 17:46:16.678  736.0147705
```

I can extract the values: they are of type `double`. For instance, the 8 bytes `00 00 00 60 59 D5 86 40` correspond to `730.6686401`.

But I am stumped by how to extract the datetime format. I know that it is buried in this string somewhere. How can I figure out what format the time is in?

I have been using Python's `struct` module for the type conversion.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Judging by the other 2 float values, encoded as doubles, there are only 9 bytes between these to encode the date-time value.

Comment: Also, the sequence [08 1E D0 08] repeats 6 times, always 13 bytes apart. Are there only 3 values in this block, or are there more than 3?

Comment: @aruisdante: I'd say there are at least 6 sets in there.

Comment: The sequence [E8 X5] also repeats (7 in this case, but looks like this block may be truncated and there would have been another 08 1E sequence), where X is a varying number, 2 bytes before the 08 1E squence

Comment: Can 8 bytes be enough to store the information?

Comment: Sure, 32bit integer microseconds, 32bit integer minutes since Unix epoch.

Comment: Or single 64bit double seconds since epoch

Comment: @aruisdante the sequence is truncated.

Comment: The ``00 00 00 60 13 F8 86 40`` that appears in the middle corresponds to ``735.0094604``.  This doesn't exactly match the decoded values you show.  Is this because I'm failing at understanding it, or because the decoded values are somehow not corresponding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the 8 bytes immediately before one of the `double`, and consider it as an integer (low-endian, like the double), then you get the following numbers:

```
635040567715583464
635040567741183464
635040567766783464
```

If you divide these numbers by 10**7, then you get the date as a number of seconds (and fractional seconds).  At least it corresponds in the minutes, seconds, and fractions of seconds.  For the hours I get an off-by-two error (timezone?).  For the complete date, the day number 735000(*) corresponds to the 5/13/2013 as follows.  It's the number of days from the year 1:

```
>>> datetime.date(1,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(735000)
datetime.date(2013, 5, 13)
```

(*) that's any of these numbers divided by 10**7 * 60 * 60 * 24

Or in a single step:

```
>>> x = 635040567715583464 / 10.**7 / 86400
>>> datetime.datetime(1,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(x)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 13, 15, 46, 11, 558353)
```

Comment: `datetime` supports ordinals (`datetime.datetime.fromordinal(735000)`). So the numbers are offsets from a 1/1/1 00:00:00 epoch instead of the UNIX epoch?

Comment: so `ordinal, rem = divmod(635040567715583464, 10**7 * 86400)`, then `datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ordinal) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=rem/10.0)` gives you the correct date `datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 12, 15, 46, 11, 558346)`, in UTC presumably.

Comment: I'm unsure what exactly `fromordinal(735000)` does, but the result is one day off (the 12th instead of the 13th).  Of course the final result is still 2 hours off, so maybe we should really use `fromordinal()` and consider the result to be 22 or 26 hours off instead.

Comment: `fromordinal()` interprets the integer as days since 1/1/0001. If there is an off-by-one in there that should be easily corrected.

Comment: I dug into the 2 hour difference. Out could be due to the fact that the data was collected during European Summer Time. @Armin Rigo, does the time conversion give us the time in UTC?

Comment: With the timezone difference this makes sense. Thank you @ArminRigo and Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ``fromordinal(1)`` actually gives 1/1/0001, and ``fromordinal(0)`` fails.  Still unsure what ``fromordinal()`` is for.

Comment: @ArminRigo: Doesn't the documentation tell you? `.fromordinal()` is an offset, with `1` meaning `January 1st, 0001`, `2` meaning `January 2nd, 0001`, etc. Not sure what the confusion is here. Clearly the numbers mean something *similar*, just not exactly the same. Using `.fromordinal()` *could* be a *very efficient way to convert the values*, that's all. Your `timedelta()` approach is another.

Comment: Instead of `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1)` you could use `datetime.datetime.min`.